How can I add a new component to footer in docusaurus?
I want to remove the default footer from docusaurus.config:
footer: {
        style: 'dark',
        links: [
          {
            title: 'Docs',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Tutorial',
                to: '/',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'Community',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Stack Overflow',
                href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusaurus',
              },
              {
                label: 'Discord',
                href: 'https://discordapp.com/invite/docusaurus',
              },
              {
                label: 'Twitter',
                href: 'https://twitter.com/docusaurus',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'More',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Blog',
                to: '/blog',
              },
              {
                label: 'GitHub',
                href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'More',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Blog',
                to: '/blog',
              },
              {
                label: 'GitHub',
                href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        copyright: `Copyright © ${new Date().getFullYear()}`,
      }

And add instead of this my new component, footer.js.
How can I do this?
I asked ChatGPT, and his solutions was this:
footer: {
      style: 'dark',
      links: [], // Optionally leave empty if links are managed in your custom component
      copyright: '',
      component: require.resolve('./src/components/FooterComponent.js'), // Add this line
    }

but this doesn't work.

According to documentation there is no component property in footer object.
In our project we had same issue: replace default footer with custom one.
It is possible to do with Swizzling https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling
You can swizzle Footer component and then apply custom layout and styles.
In configuration section you should define copyright and links like you do. Then in footer component you can access this information and put it in necessary places in your custom layout.
  const { footer } = useThemeConfig();
  const { copyright, links = [], logo = {} } = footer;

